Unified definition of log resolution and relative canonical divisor
I want to deal with log resolutions on the most basic level possible to understand it in the easiest case of a divisor defined by a function in $\mathbb A^d$. I like very much the definition that Mihnea Popa uses in Definition 4.1 and Remark 4.2 of his notes:

Let $f \in \mathbb C[x_1,\ldots,x_d]$ be a polynomial. A log resolution of $f$ (or rather of the pair $(\mathbb A^d,V(f)))$ is a proper birational morphism $\mu: Y \to \mathbb A^d$, where $Y$ is a smooth variety and for every point $p \in Y$ there exists a "system of algebraic coordinates" $y_1,\ldots,y_n$ such that $\mu^*f = h y_1^{a_1} \cdots y_d^{a_d}$, where the $a_i$ are non-negative integers and $h$ is invertible around $p$.

I have four questions:

Is this intended to mean that the $y_1,\ldots,y_d$ form a regular sequence in the local ring $\mathcal O_{Y,p}$ and that, as an element of this local ring, $\mu^*f = h  y_1^{a_1} \cdots y_d^{a_d}$, where $h$ is a unit?

After his definition, Popa then writes $\mu^* \text{div}(f) = \sum_{i = 1}^m a_i \cdot E_i$, where $E_i$ are either components of the proper transform or of the exceptional divisor. Then, he defines the relative canonical divisor $K_{Y/\mathbb A^d} := \text{div}(\text{Jac}(\mu))$, where $\text{Jac}(\mu) := \det(\partial\mu_i/\partial y_j)_{i,j}$. How should I make sense of these partial derivatives, if the $y_i$ are a regular sequence in $\mathcal O_{Y,p}$?

He claims that $K_{Y/\mathbb A^d} = \sum_{i = 1}^m b_i \cdot E_i$, that is, only the prime divisors of $\mu^*\text{div}(f)$ are involved in the relative canonical divisor. How does one see that?

How is this definition equivalent to the following one, used in a paper by Teitler? A log resolution of $f$ is a proper birational map $\mu: Y \to \mathbb A^d$, with $Y$ smooth, such that the total transform $f\cdot \mathcal O_Y = \mathcal O_Y(-F)$ is locally principal and $F + \text{Exc}(\mu)$ is a divisor with normal crossing support.


If anyone could help me with these questions or give me a hint for consistent and exact references, I would be very grateful! Thank you!
